# How to reload my view when my app becomes active again?

Tags: iphone, ios4

Let say someone is using my app and the change the settings in the settings bundle, when they come back to my app I would like my view to update (via my updating method) according to those settings. I've tried many different things but I just can't get it to work.

What is the best way to implement this kind of behavior for my iPhone app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's worth noting that you're not limited to the AppDelegate; you can listen for these events from anywhere in your code with an `NSNotification`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639859/handling-applicationdidbecomeactive/3639903#3639903) for more details on how to listen for `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`.

Comment: Interesting, never knew that notification was fired!

Answer (score 6):

in your `AppDelegate` put these methods:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Called as part of  transition from the background to the active state: here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
     */
}


- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
     */
}
```

Then you have hooks to do whatever you want.