# best way to add a hook to a UIApplicationDelegate with an air native extension

Tags: ios, air, air-native-extension

I'm trying to add a hook to get my native extension called when the UIApplicationDelegate is called for application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken and others.

I don't think changing the delegate will work as it will break air stuff, doing [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setDelegate:delegate];

So what is the best way to do that ?
Should I dynamically create a subclass of the delegate and add the methods I want to it ?
I didn't find anything about that on the Air documentation, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Everything is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204993/push-notification-ios-native-extension-for-adobe-air

Answer (score 0):

Yes, only one appdelegate can exist. You can register for all those same functions that the appdelegate receives. I'm new to xcode/air, but as I was skimming other info, I came across this answer for you.