# Creating settings for an app in iOS 5

Tags: ios5, appsettings

How can I add settings to an app? I've never done this before and I don't know where to begin. I would like to make an app where user would set his/her info (like time interval, gender, ...). Uncle Google gives me results that help users of iOS 5 not developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keywords are: `Settings.bundle` and `NSUserDefaults`. There is a lot information in Google.

Also, check out this awesome framework: [InAppSettingsKit](http://www.inappsettingskit.com/).

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. It was useful. Got it working. Just one more thing... I open my app, it shows I'm a male (default setting). Then I go to Settings->my app->Gender setting and change it to female... when I go back to my app, a label (i have some to display settings for now) showing gender doesn't change. I set label text in viewDidLoad. Any ideas? I followed these instructions: http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/08/application-preferences.html

Comment: Glad to help you. 
What happens if you restart your app?

Also, try method `applicationWillEnterForeground`. `viewWillAppear` doesn't really get called after app reopening from background.

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is called just when your ViewController is created. It's even further from `viewWillAppear` :)

Comment: in app delegate:
`- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
NSString *value = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"gender"];    
}`

in view controller:
`AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSString *test = appDelegate.value;`
test gives me (null) :/

Comment: Is `value` a local variable? If yes, then, of course, it won't work, You need to set `NSString *value` as a property of the `AppDelegate` (something like public class variable in c++)

Comment: What does `NSLog(@"%@", value)` in `applicationWillEnterForeground` say? Is it called? Also, make sure you write `value = [defaults...]` or even `self.value`, **not** the `NSString *value = ...`, in case you are creating local variable.

Comment: Why not just call `[[..defaults..] stringForKey:@"gender"]` ? Do you really need the `value` here?:)
Try using `(<your AppDelegateClassName>)([[UIApplication....]])`

Comment: Google what methods are there to see that app is active, view is loaded, will appear and when they are called. Or just put NSLogs to see that yourself.

Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639859/handling-applicationdidbecomeactive , it tells how to interact properly.