# Refresh ios UIViewController on applicationDidBecomeActive

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uiapplication

I need to re-create my current `UIViewController` in my iOS application on `applicationDidBecomeActive`. In my code, I adding a lot of runtime graphics to screen, so I think best way to completely recreate it.

I need to solve 2 tasks:

1. Determine, which UIViewController currently on display (I change view controllers with **presentModalViewController** command).
2. Completely repaint it.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: I think the best answer is in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639859/handling-applicationdidbecomeactive

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

may be helpful for u :)

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{  
   UIViewController* root = _window.rootViewController;
   UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)root;
   YourViewController * mycontroller = (YourViewController *)[[navController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
   [mycontroller reloadInputViews];
}
```