# Can’t join quickblox dialog after app was in background

Tags: ios, quickblox

I’ve created chat as described at tutorial:
[SimpleSample-chat users-ios](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios)

All works fine except this:
When app goes to background I disconnect it, when it returns  to foreground – connect:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[QBChat instance] disconnect];
}
 
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[QBChat instance] connectWithUser:user];
}
```

However when I try to join dialog(which I successfully used earlier) onJoin and onJoinFailed blocks have never called and my messages are not sent. So now I have to get this dialog all the time I return from background. My messages are sent, but I have quite long delay before I can send messages: QBRequest dialogsForPage is quite slow.
Can you help me with this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Try in this way:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639859/handling-applicationdidbecomeactive-how-can-a-view-controller-respond-to-the

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with latest SDK(v2.4.6 — Oct 23, 2015)