# How to know if ViewController is visible again

Tags: swift

How do I know if the ViewController is visible again?

I tried putting the `print` command inside `viewDidAppear`. Run the app. Press the home button. Return to the app but `viewDidAppera` dont get executed.

i am trying to execute a code right after the app becomes visible again.

How do I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling applicationDidBecomeActive - "How can a view controller respond to the app becoming Active?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639859/handling-applicationdidbecomeactive-how-can-a-view-controller-respond-to-the)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your print statement in the AppDelegate for `application: WillEnterForeground` OR `application: didBecomeActive` both of those are called at different times when the user returns to the application. Use one or the other depending on at what point you'd like to call or reference your code