# Location permission alert button callback

Tags: ios, swift, callback, alert, mobile-development

How to trigger action when the button of location permission alert is pressed? I want to perform segue after allow or cancel button is pressed.

Comment: After the dialog is dismissed your app will resume active, so you can observe the did become active NSNotification

Comment: Thank you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639859/handling-applicationdidbecomeactive-how-can-a-view-controller-respond-to-the Here is solution for your answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have taken help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639859/handling-applicationdidbecomeactive-how-can-a-view-controller-respond-to-the) answer  and  [Apple's Developer guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html) . 
You can achieve it by setting observor over **applicationDidBecomeActive** method of Appdelegate using **NotificationCenter** . Below is the code to achieve your task .

Put the following code in the viewDidLoad of your ViewController .

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector: #selector(doSomeThing), name: .UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
```

Then when ever **didBecomeActive** is called from **Appdelegate** this function will be called ... So you can put the action you want to perform in this function

```
func doSomeThing(){

}
```

Also put the following code in the the **viewDidDisappear** of the **same ViewController** to remove the observer otherwise your app will crash

```
 NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self,name: .UIApplicationDidBecomeActive,object: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks! really helped me out.