# How to call viewController's method in appdelegate

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, nsnotification, application-lifecycle

I want viewController's method for update data.

So I want use viewController's update method when `applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication)`.

how it possible?

Comment: `class_obj.method()` is not working?

Comment: You really need to do some research before asking questions on SO. Please read [Ask] before you ask another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you (tested in Swift 4)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(applicationDidBecomeActive),
                                               name: Notification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive,
                                               object: nil)
    }

}

@objc func applicationDidBecomeActive() {
    print("UIApplicationDidBecomeActive")
}
```

**Note**: Don't forget to remove observer when your view controller is no longer in use/memory (as this is an application level observer and will be called every time your application becomes active, whether your view controller is active or not.

Here is code to remove observer:

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self,
                                          name: Notification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive,
                                          object: nil)
```

Comment: I did that. Thanks!

Comment: @usinuniverse - Don't forget to remove observer when your view controller is no longer in use/memory. See an updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Use `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3639903/7104617).