# Is there a Swift macOS/Cocoa API that can detect when the current foreground app changes?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

Is there a Swift API that can notify when the current active/foreground window changes and provide information about the title of the foreground window, the application name, etc?

Something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639859/handling-applicationdidbecomeactive-how-can-a-view-controller-respond-to-the), but not only monitoring the current application but all running apps across the system.

Answer (score 2):

There is the [didActivateApplicationNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1535049-didactivateapplicationnotificati) in `NSWorkspace`.

> A notification that the workspace posts when the Finder is about to activate an app.

However [NSRunningApplication](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsrunningapplication) which is the object of the posted notification doesn't provide information about the active window.