# Swift App - Cannot find 'SKStoreProductViewController' in scope

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am trying to do a simple app to open a deeplink to the Salesforce app, or redirect to the App Store if not installed.

I am launching the code from the View Controller but when trying to use SKStoreProductViewController it is telling me it is not in scope.

Any ideas on why this is the case?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        guard let url = URL(string: "salesforce1://sObject/--------/view") else {
                return
            }
        
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            // deep link to Einstein
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
        else {
            // app store if not installed
            let vc = SKStoreProductViewController() //THROWS ERROR
            
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please import StoreKit framework

```
import StoreKit
```

Comment: One follow up question. This runs only when the app is opened initially. How can I get it to run every time the app is reactivated?

Comment: @Steven: have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639859/ (scroll down for Swift answers).